# Finding missing integers in a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

I had to find the missing integers (randomly generated in the range of 0-9) in an array with length = 10. I had the idea to sort the array and then check for each array if it equals the position in the array. I came up with the following code:

```
public void nichtGetroffen(){
    s.quickSort(enten, 0, enten.length -1);
    sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < enten.length; i++){ 
        if(enten[i] != i){
            System.out.print(i + "");
            sum = sum +1;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't and I unfortunately don't have an idea how to solve this. (enten is the name of the array)

Comment: Please clarify. You have a set of X  integesr in range of [Nmin,NMax] and you want to find "gaps" in the set, is that it?

Comment: the original task was: Create an array with length 10 filled with random integers in a range of 0 to 9. Then give out the missing integers (because some integers can be doupletts) repeat this function n times. then calculate the average number of missing integers (that is why I add 1 to sum for every missing integer so I can divide it through n in the end). I hope this clears things up.

Comment: You say how many missing integers *plural*. Do you mean there is more than one integer missing?

Comment: Exactly. The numbers in the array are generated randomly from 0-9. So it can happen that 4 slots will be 9 and another 3 slots are 7. You get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the array, if the next element is more than 1 greater than the current element, you've got missing numbers. Then, just look for missing numbers at the start and end of the array.

```
s.quickSort(enten, 0, enten.length -1);

// Print missing numbers less than the smallest element.
for (int j = 0; j < enten[0]; ++j) {
  System.out.println(j);
}

// Print missing numbers between elements.
for (int i = 1; i < enten.length; ++i) {
  // If enten[i - 1] + 1 >= enten[i], this loop body never runs.
  for (int j = enten[i - 1] + 1; j < enten[i]; ++j) {
    System.out.println(j);
  }
}

// Print missing numbers greater than the largest element.
for (int j = enten[enten.length-1] + 1; j <= 9; ++j) {
  System.out.println(j);
}
```

Comment: Ok this solved it. Thank you very much. Could you maybe explain each step a bit more I have to present this on tuesday and if I don't exactly know each step I will have a bit of a problem.

Comment: @Dämonplay why don't you step through it with a debugger or on paper? I don't want to be obtuse, but I don't want to destroy your learning opportunity either.

Comment: Ok good point. You are right this is a learning experience. I forget this sometimes. But I will do this tomorrow sleep is important after all. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Dämonplay Consider using Arrays.sort(enten) instead of your own sort implementation. This is an important utility class with lots of other methods you should get familliar as a beginner.

Comment: @Journeycorner ok I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of why it doesn't work:

Say that the sorted array contains the following numbers: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9`. How many numbers are missing from this array? Only one. We're missing the number `0`.

How many numbers are in their "right" place? Only the last `9`. This is why your code will return `9` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understend well your question, fill a `set` collection with the array you got and then, check the lenght is equals to 10.

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(arrayOfRandomNumbers);
if (set.size() == 10) {
   //all elements in array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this it so use `Set` and its property of having unique elements only:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // randomizing
    int nMin = 5;
    int nMax = 50;
    int x = 20;
    Random r = new Random();
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        int val = nMin + r.nextInt(nMax - nMin);
        System.out.println(val);
        arr[i] = val;
    }

    // detection

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    List<Integer> missing = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = nMin; i < nMax; i++) {
        if (!set.contains(i)) {
            missing.add(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Missing elements count " + missing.size());
    System.out.println("Missing elements: " + missing.toString());
}
```

This will give you all the missing interegs from the set of X(20) random integers between nMin(5) and nMax(50) inclusive;

Comment: I never heard of set before so I know what I am going to look into now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution to your "original task" you have mentioned in the comment:

```
public class Gaps {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int runs = 100;
        int nMin = 0;
        int nMax = 10;
        int x = 10;

        double missingSum = 0;

        for (int run = 0; run < runs; run++) {
            Integer[] arr = randomize(nMin, nMax, x);
            List<Integer> missing = getMissingElements(nMin, nMax, arr);
            missingSum += missing.size();
        }
        double avg = missingSum / runs;
        System.out.println("Missing elements avarage count: " + avg);

    }

    private static List<Integer> getMissingElements(int nMin, int nMax, Integer[] arr) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        List<Integer> missing = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = nMin; i < nMax; i++) {
            if (!set.contains(i)) {
                missing.add(i);
            }
        }
        return missing;
    }

    private static Integer[] randomize(int nMin, int nMax, int x) {
        Random r = new Random();
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            int val = nMin + r.nextInt(nMax - nMin);
            arr[i] = val;
        }
        return arr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Fortunately I have the rest of the program ready. And it is a bit shorter and compacter than this version.